# dispatch_get_main_queue inside dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my VC1, I run code that I took from online blogs:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = 
    [session dataTaskWithRequest:request 
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
       [self.delegate didReceiveResponse:response data:data error:error];
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
});
```

My question is:

- which part of this code will run in main thread and which part will run in background or non-main thread?
- I want `didReceiveResponse` to run in main thread to update UI.
- Everything else should run in background.
- Little bit of explanation would be useful.

Comment: Hmmm, what do you suppose `dispatch_get_main_queue()` might mean...?

Comment: @matt...I assumed the dataTask will be submitted to main queue....but the task itself will run in background thread....IOS will take care of running network tasks in background queue...once task completes, completionHandler will be run in main queue thread.....maybe I am wrong

Comment: I thought dataTask.resume will run in non-main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the code all inside out. You need to create a background queue to run the task and specify that the completion handler should be run on the main queue:

```
session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:someConfiguration delegate:someDelegate delegateQueue:[NSOperation mainQueue]];

...

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = 
    [session dataTaskWithRequest:request 
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
       [self.delegate didReceiveResponse:response data:data error:error];
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
});
```

The above code sets up the session so completion handlers are called on the main queue and then it creates and resumes the data task in the background.

As you had it, you specified that the data task was to be created and start on the main queue and you gave no indication of where the completion handler was to be run.

Comment: Thanks...will understand this better now...will accept once allowed!

Comment: I wanted to thank you once more....for the explanation...saved lot of time and code is clean....